# Rearrange the letters and Compare two words

Tags: text-processing, awk, sort

I have a problem to compare a long list of names.

```
RamaKrishna  KrishnaRama 
IndiaUS      USIndia
```

shall be compared and they are to be declared as equal.

I wanted to solve this by rearranging all characters in each word alphabetically like this

```
adiiNSU adiiNSU
```

then comparing each word. How can I do this using bash script.

Comment: show how should look the expected output

Comment: are the words always in pair in each line which are to be compared? what did you try to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended GNU **`AWK`** solution:

Sample `inputfile` contents:

```
RamaKrishna  KrishnaRama 
IndiaUS      USIndia
UkraineMotherland RepublicUkraine
```

---

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@str_val_asc" }
     { 
         len=split($1,w1,""); split($2,w2,""); asort(w1); asort(w2); not_eq=0; 
         for (i=1; i<=len; i++) if (w2[i]=="" || w1[i] != w2[i]) { not_eq=1; break } 
         print $0,"-",(not_eq? "not equal":"equal") 
     }' inputfile
```

The output:

```
RamaKrishna  KrishnaRama  - equal
IndiaUS      USIndia - equal
UkraineMotherland RepublicUkraine - not equal
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `perl` here:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -lane '
  sub rearrange {
    return join "", sort split("", $_[0])
  }
  print if rearrange($F[0]) eq rearrange($F[1])' < file
```

Would print those lines of `file` where the first field is the same as the second after that *rearranging*.